# How to show composable from edge-to-edge with display cutout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Rendering edge-to-edge works fine without a display cutout. But as soon as there is a notch, hiding the status bar doesn't result in additional space for my composable.

What am I doing wrong?

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/display-cutout

All screenshots are taken from an Android device emulator running Android 14. I get the same result on a physical device running Android 13.

The demo app draws a red line along the edges of a canvas filling the available space on the screen.
Code snippets to replace `// additional stuff to be added here` are mentioned above screenshots.

First it respects the system bar insets.

```
class MainActivity : androidx.activity.ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // additional stuff to be added here
        setContent {
            Greeting()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        drawRect(Color.Red, style = Stroke(20.dp.toPx()))
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Now let's ignore the insets for the system bars and let the system bars cover the upper and lower parts of the red frame.
`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

[image] [image]

Now hide the system bars and see the red frame surrounding the whole screen.

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
```

[image] [image]

Why does the canvas on the right (device with display cutout) does not use the full height of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shortEdges` cutout mode should fix it. Just add this item to your app theme:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Derek is correct. But it depends on the API level. There is e.g. also this value always
Maybe better using the upcoming version of the implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0-alpha03")
The enableEdgeToEdge() function will automatically set the windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode to always or shortEdges depending on the API level of the device.